# How to adjust toolbar-style TabController height?

Tags: macos, cocoa, storyboard, nstabview

I would like to use a TabViewController in my Cocoa application that is neatly merged with the titlebar. The merging part was easy--in the storyboard I simply set the TabViewController to "Toolbar". I get the following result:

[image]

How can adjust the height of the toolbar/titlebar so that the tabs don't look ridiculously oversized?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578085/resizing-window-to-view-controller-size-in-storyboard/48869175#48869175